# Core ML Object detection for different sized images

Tags: ios, machine-learning, coreml

I've trained the model to recognize rectangles from the images. I worked fine but only with specific images (as I think depends on specific aspect ratio).
For example:

[valid example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieorn.png)

enter image description here
But when I started to use the same image but with a different size, it doesn't work.

[invalid example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXRkn.png)

Could someone tell me why it works like this? And how can I fix it?

What I do to make a request:

```
let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, orientation: image.cgImageOrientation, options: [:])

    self.request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (request, error) in
        guard let observations = request.results as? [VNRecognizedObjectObservation] else {
            return
        }

        self.visualizeObservations(observations: observations)
        print(observations)
    }

    request.imageCropAndScaleOption = .scaleFill

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        do {
            try requestHandler.perform([self.request])
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error in performing Image request: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Also, I would like to know, in which cases the model can detect an object in CreateML GUI but can't on the screen for the same image?

UPD:
I have already found the solution.
The root cause was the invalid output and when I changed

```
let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, orientation: image.cgImageOrientation, options: [:])
```

To

```
let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(data: image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!, orientation: image.cgImageOrientation, options: [:])
```

Solve the issue.

Comment: You can fix it by training the model on images of many different sizes.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans thank you for your response. Maybe you know,  in which cases the model can detect an object in CreateML GUI but can't with VNImageRequest for the same image?

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct `imageCropAndScaleOption` with your Vision request (see `VNCoreMLModel`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD: I have already funded the solution. The root cause was the invalid output and when I changed

```
let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, orientation: image.cgImageOrientation, options: [:])
```

To

```
let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(data: image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!, orientation: image.cgImageOrientation, options: [:])
```

Solve the issue.

Comment: I will be able to do it in 15 hours :)